# Deploying a python Flask application with Jenkins and executing it

Tags: python, linux, jenkins, flask, raspberry-pi

I am trying to do auto-deployment of a Python Flask application using Jenkins and then run it by using shell command on a Raspberry Pi server.

Here are some **background info**,

Before using Jenkins, my deployment and execution process was manual described below:

1. FTP to the directory where my Python scripts and Python venv are located
2. Replace Flask application scripts using FTP
3. Activate virtual environment to of Python(3.5) through the terminal on Raspberry Pi ("./venv/bin/activate")
4. Run myFlaskApp.py by executing "python myFlaskApp.py" in terminal

Now I have integrated Jenkins with the deployment/execution process described below:

1. Code change pushed to github
2. Jenkins automatically pulls from github
3. Jenkins deploy files to specified directories by executing shell commands
4. Jenkins then activates virtual environment and run myFlaskApp.py by bashing a .sh script in the shell terminal.

Now **the problem** that I am having is on step 4, because a Flask app has to always be alive, my Jenkins will never "finish building successfully", it will always be in a loading state as the Flask app is running on the shell terminal Jenkins is using.

Now my **question**:
What is the correct approach that I should be taking in order to activate myFlaskApp.py with Jenkins after deploying the files while not causing it to be "locked down" by the build process?

I have read up about Docker, SubShell and the Linux utility "Screen". Will any of these tools be useful to assist me in my situation right now and which approach should I be taking?

Answer (score 2):

The simple and robust solution (in my opinion) is to use [Supervisor](http://supervisord.org/) which is available in Debian as `supervisor` package. It allows you do make a daemon from script like your app, it can spawn multiple processes, watch if app doesn't crash and if it does it can start it again.

Note about `virtualenv` - you don't need to activate venv to use it. You just need to point appropriate Python executable (`your_venv/bin/python`) instead of default one. For example:

```
$ ./venv/bin/python myFlaskApp.py
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create these files for deployment over jenkins.

**Code can be found:**  https://github.com/ishwar6/django_ci_cd

1. This will work for both flask as well as django.
2. initial-setup.sh - This file is the first file to look at when setting up this project. It installs the required packages to make this project work such as Nginx, Jenkins, Python etc. Refer to the youtube video to see how and when it is used.
3. Jenkinsfile - This file contains the definition of the stages in the pipeline. The stages in this project's pipeline are Setup Python Virtual Environment, Setup gunicorn service and Setup Nginx. The stages in this pipeline just does two things. First it makes a file executable and then runs the file. The file carries out the commands that is described by the stage description.
4. envsetup.sh - This file sets up the python virtual environment, installs the python packages and then creates log files that will be used by Nginx.
5. gunicorn.sh - This file runs some Django management commands like migration commands and static files collection commands. It also sets up the gunicorn service that will be running the gunicorn server in the background.
6. nginx.sh - This file sets up Nginx with a configuration file that points Nginx to the gunicorn service that is running our application. This allows Nginx serve our application. I have followed a digital ocean article to setup this file. You can go through the video once to replicate sites-available and sites-enabled scanerio.
7. app.conf - This is an Nginx server configuration file. This file is used to setup Nginx as proxy server to gunicorn. For this configuration to work, change the value of server_name to the IP address or domain name of your server.

Answer (score 0):

nohup worked for me.
So I basically run the following command:

```
nohup python your_app.py &
```